# Nested Case Statement in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case-statement

I am getting an error stating missing right parenthesis but I cannot for the life of me figure out where in my statement.

```
(CASE WHEN A.AUTH_STRT_DT > CD.SVC_STRT_DT THEN 
 (CASE WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_STRT_DT - CD.SVC_STRT_DT) = 1 THEN '1 DAY BEFORE' 
      WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_STRT_DT - CD.SVC_STRT_DT) BETWEEN 2 AND 3 THEN '3 DAYS BEFORE'
      WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_STRT_DT - CD.SVC_STRT_DT) = 4 THEN '4 DAYS BEFORE'
      WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_STRT_DT - CD.SVC_STRT_DT) BETWEEN 5 AND 21 THEN '21 DAYS BEFORE'
      WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_STRT_DT - CD.SVC_STRT_DT) BETWEEN 22 AND 90 THEN '90 DAY BEFORE'
      ELSE 'OVER 90' END)  
WHEN A.AUTH_END_DT < CD.SVC_END_DT THEN 
  (CASE WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_END_DT < CD.SVC_END_DT) = 1 THEN '1 DAY AFTER' 
        WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_END_DT < CD.SVC_END_DT) BETWEEN 2 AND 3 THEN '3 DAYS AFTER'
        WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_END_DT < CD.SVC_END_DT) = 4 THEN '4 DAYS AFTER'
        WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_END_DT < CD.SVC_END_DT) BETWEEN 5 AND 21 THEN '21 DAYS AFTER'
        WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_END_DT < CD.SVC_END_DT) BETWEEN 22 AND 90 THEN '90 DAYS AFTER'
        ELSE 'OVER 90' END) 
ELSE '0 DAY' END) AS DAYSLAPSED
```

Comment: you use sql developer tool where you can get line number for exact syntax error.

Comment: I think those 'Less Than' inequalities in your second nested Case statement should be minus signs.

Comment: The parentheses themselves are correct. The error is somewhere else, and I think JNevill has found out where. Actually, the outer parentheses aren't needed at all, although they are allowed.

Comment: @Ramki unfortunately I am using Toad and its not as user friendly.

Comment: @Golez, In some RDBMS/Client combinations the outer parentheses are necessary :/

Comment: @JNevill yes! I went copy and paste crazy, thank you!!

Comment: Sql developer is free download you can down load.  its need jave RTE in your machine.

Answer (score 3):

`ABS ( x < y )` is not valid.  In the second section, see the conditions replaced with a minus sign.

```
(CASE WHEN A.AUTH_STRT_DT > CD.SVC_STRT_DT THEN 
 (CASE WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_STRT_DT - CD.SVC_STRT_DT) = 1 THEN '1 DAY BEFORE' 
      WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_STRT_DT - CD.SVC_STRT_DT) BETWEEN 2 AND 3 THEN '3 DAYS BEFORE'
      WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_STRT_DT - CD.SVC_STRT_DT) = 4 THEN '4 DAYS BEFORE'
      WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_STRT_DT - CD.SVC_STRT_DT) BETWEEN 5 AND 21 THEN '21 DAYS BEFORE'
      WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_STRT_DT - CD.SVC_STRT_DT) BETWEEN 22 AND 90 THEN '90 DAY BEFORE'
      ELSE 'OVER 90' END)  
WHEN A.AUTH_END_DT < CD.SVC_END_DT THEN 
  (CASE WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_END_DT - CD.SVC_END_DT) = 1 THEN '1 DAY AFTER' 
        WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_END_DT - CD.SVC_END_DT) BETWEEN 2 AND 3 THEN '3 DAYS AFTER'
        WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_END_DT - CD.SVC_END_DT) = 4 THEN '4 DAYS AFTER'
        WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_END_DT - CD.SVC_END_DT) BETWEEN 5 AND 21 THEN '21 DAYS AFTER'
        WHEN ABS(A.AUTH_END_DT - CD.SVC_END_DT) BETWEEN 22 AND 90 THEN '90 DAYS AFTER'
        ELSE 'OVER 90' END) 
ELSE '0 DAY' END) AS DAYSLAPSED
```

Comment: That's it! And now, looking at it, you can see the inner case is the same two times, except the word 'BEFORE' or 'AFTER', so you could shorting this by having that case once, and use the outer case to concat the right word only. ;-)